# Error when creating an Access table with a CHECK constraint via DDL

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
CREATE TABLE Food_Supply_Disp
(
Supply_Disp text,
SD_2008 DOUBLE,
SD_2009 DOUBLE,
SD_2010 DOUBLE,

CHECK (SD_2008 > 0.0 )

);
```

Comment: Try this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903256/im-unsure-whats-wrong-when-i-declare-these-variables-in-sql


Double is not an sql data type.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to add a CHECK constraint to an Access table, but my understanding is that the following restrictions apply:

1. The CHECK constraint must be added *after* the table has been created, and
2. The DDL statement must be executed via an ADO connection.

In Access VBA that would be something like this:

```vbs
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Set con = CurrentProject.Connection
con.Execute _
        "CREATE TABLE Food_Supply_Disp ( " & _
            "Supply_Disp TEXT(100), " & _
            "SD_2008 DOUBLE, " & _
            "SD_2009 DOUBLE, " & _
            "SD_2010 DOUBLE " & _
        ")"
con.Execute _
        "ALTER TABLE Food_Supply_Disp " & _
            "ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK_SD_2008 " & _
                "CHECK (SD_2008 > 0.0)"
Set con = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is valid Access DDL, but as Gord mentioned it must be executed from ADO.  If you try to execute that statement from the query designer or with `CurrentDb.Execute`, it will trigger error #3289, *"Syntax error in CONSTRAINT clause."*

However I suggest you consider including a name for the constraint.  The reason is that the constraint name is included in the error message when the user attempts to input a value which violates the constraint.  And, if you don't supply a name for the constraint, Access will make one up for you ... and it will not be helpful in the error message.  For example, here is the error message I got after executing your `CREATE TABLE` and then attempting to `INSERT` -1 into `SD_2008`.

*"One or more values are prohibited by the validation rule 'Check_7411684B_BA50_4EEF' set for 'Food_Supply_Disp'.
Enter a value that the expression for this field can accept."*

But adding a meaningful constraint name ...

```sql
CREATE TABLE Food_Supply_Disp
    (
        Supply_Disp text,
        SD_2008 DOUBLE,
        SD_2009 DOUBLE,
        SD_2010 DOUBLE,
        CONSTRAINT [SD_2008 must be > 0] CHECK (SD_2008 > 0.0 )
    );
```

... gives me a more useful error message ...

*"One or more values are prohibited by the validation
rule 'SD_2008 must be > 0' set for 'Food_Supply_Disp'.
Enter a value that the expression for this field can accept."*

It's still not a great error message, but better than the first.

A secondary issue is that executing your `CREATE TABLE` with `Supply_Disp text` from ADO will make `Supply_Disp` a memo field.  If you want a regular text field qualify the field length ... `Supply_Disp text(255)`

Finally, you can do what you want with Access DDL under ADO.  However, for this one, I would prefer to set the field's *Validation Rule* and *Validation Text* properties in table design instead of using a `CHECK` constraint.  You can do that from the user interface or by using VBA to modify the table's `DAO.TableDef`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use float and not double as double is not a valid sql data type.

Comment: Actually `DOUBLE` is a valid column type specifier in Access SQL. (ref: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/721312/2144390))

Comment: Yes but not in MS SQL, which I think the question opener is trying to do.

Comment: This question appears to be a follow-up to their recent question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21650135/2144390).